# How to connect bones in Matplotlib/Python

Tags: python

I'm having trouble connecting the femur and tibia, finding the right angle was OK just applying it is tricky.

I've tried changing the rotation of the axis using the dega18,27 etc matrix and adding together what I thought was the correct angles but it never lines up!

How can I achieve this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
import numpy as np
import math

#notes:
#YZ
#coax is b2 femur is a9 tibia is b9 height is a1, y is b1, x is b8, z is the height of the foot , starts at 0 on the ground, angle at coax is right angled triangle from ground with top angle B1 bottom angle A1 hypotenuse is c
#leg length based on angles etc is a2 angle at bottom of iso triangle with tibia and femur is B2 the top angle at the coax is A2 a2 and b2 are at right angles fixed
#the start height is 200 and x =1 y=35, femur is 120 and tibia is 140

def rotate_vector(vector, axis, angle):
    rotation_matrix = {
        'X': np.array([[1, 0, 0],
                       [0, np.cos(angle), -np.sin(angle)],
                       [0, np.sin(angle), np.cos(angle)]]),
        'Y': np.array([[np.cos(angle), 0, np.sin(angle)],
                       [0, 1, 0],
                       [-np.sin(angle), 0, np.cos(angle)]]),
        'Z': np.array([[np.cos(angle), -np.sin(angle), 0],
                       [np.sin(angle), np.cos(angle), 0],
                       [0, 0, 1]])
    }
    return np.dot(rotation_matrix[axis], vector)

# Function to calculate coordinates of a line segment
def calculate_line(length, angle, axis):
    angle_rad = np.radians(angle)
    if axis == 'XY':
        x = [0, length * np.cos(angle_rad)]
        y = [0, length * np.sin(angle_rad)]
        z = [0, 0]
    elif axis == 'XZ':
        x = [0, length * np.cos(angle_rad)]
        y = [0, 0]
        z = [0, length * np.sin(angle_rad)]
    elif axis == 'YZ':
        x = [0, 0]
        y = [0, length * np.cos(angle_rad)]
        z = [0, length * np.sin(angle_rad)]
    return x, y, z

def calculate_endpoint_and_plot(x, y, z, length, angle, plane):
    angle_rad = np.deg2rad(angle)
    direction_vector = [length * np.cos(angle_rad), length * np.sin(angle_rad), 0]
    if plane.lower() == 'xy':
        end_point = [x + direction_vector[0], y + direction_vector[1], z]
    elif plane.lower() == 'xz':
        end_point = [x + direction_vector[0], y, z + direction_vector[1]]
    elif plane.lower() == 'yz':
        end_point = [x, y + direction_vector[0], z + direction_vector[1]]
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid plane. Please choose 'xy', 'xz', or 'yz'.")
    return end_point

# Function to update the plot
def update(val):
    rz = rh_slider.val
    fy = fy_slider.val
    fx = fx_slider.val
    ax.clear()
    ax.plot([0, 0], [0, 0], [0, rz], color='green')
    ax.plot([0, 300], [0, 0], [rz, rz], color='green')
    ax.plot([300, 300], [0, 0], [0, rz], color='green')
    ax.plot([0, 0], [0, 150], [rz, rz], color='green')
    ax.plot([0, 0], [0, 150], [rz, rz], color='green')
    ax.plot([0, 300], [150, 150], [rz, rz], color='green')
    ax.plot([300, 300], [150, 0], [rz, rz], color='green')
    femur=80
    tibia=140
    b2=35
    b1=fy
    a1 = rz
    c = math.sqrt(pow(a1, 2) + pow(b1, 2))
    A1 = math.degrees(math.asin(a1 / c))
    B1 = int(math.degrees(math.asin(b1 / c)))
    a2 = math.sqrt(pow(c, 2) - pow(b2, 2))
    A2 = int(math.degrees(math.asin(a2 / c)))
    B2 = math.degrees(math.asin(b2 / c))
    coaxra = int(B1 + A2)
    print('===============')
    print(f'a1 {a1}')
    print(f'b1 {b1}')
    print(f'c  {c}')
    print(f'A1 {A1}')
    print(f'B1 {B1}')
    print(f'a2 {a2}')
    print(f'b2 {b2}')
    print(f'A2 {A2}')
    print(f'B2 {B2}')
    print('Do math for XY')
    a8=a1
    b8=fx
    c8=a2
    a9=femur
    b9=tibia
    c9=a2
    #if fx < 0:
    print('<')
    B8=int(math.degrees(math.asin(b8/c8))) #math.acos((pow(a3,2) + pow(c3,2) - pow(b3,2))   /(2 * a3 * c3)   )))
    A8=int(math.degrees(math.asin(a8/c8))) #math.acos((pow(b3,2) + pow(c3,2) - pow(a3,2))   /(2 * b3 * c3)   )))
    B9=int(math.degrees(math.acos((pow(a9,2) + pow(c9,2) - pow(b9,2))   /(2 * a9 * c9)   )))
    A9=int(math.degrees(math.acos((pow(b9,2) + pow(c9,2) - pow(a9,2))   /(2 * b9 * c9)   )))
    C9=int(math.degrees(math.acos((pow(a9,2) + pow(b9,2) - pow(c9,2))   /(2 * a9 * b9)   )))
    F=90-B8-B9
    print(f'B8 {B8}')
    print(f'A8 {A8}')
    print(f'A9 {A9}')
    print(f'B9 {B9}')
    print(f'C9 {C9}')
    print(f'F {F}')
    print(f'c9 {c9}')
    print(f'c8 {c8}')
    
    #---------------------------    COAX
    length = b2
    angle = dega27[coaxra]  # Angle in degrees
    plane = 'YZ'
    end_point = calculate_endpoint_and_plot(0, 0, a1, length, angle, plane)
    ax.plot([0,end_point[0] ],[0, end_point[1] ], [a1, end_point[2]], color='red')
    clx,cly,clz=end_point[0],end_point[1],end_point[2]
    
    
    # plot the vertical leg line (length)
    #---------------------------    COAX TO BASE
    length = c
    angle = dega27[A2+B1-90]  # Angle in degrees
    plane = 'YZ'
    end_point = calculate_endpoint_and_plot(clx+fx, cly, clz, length, angle, plane)
    ax.plot([clx,end_point[0] ],[cly, end_point[1] ], [clz, end_point[2]], color='green')
    ax.scatter(clx, cly, clz, color='red', label='Coax')
    vlx,vly,vlz=end_point[0],end_point[1],end_point[2]
    print(vlx,vly,vlz)
    
    #----try drawing fron end up at angle A9+A8----------------------    TIBIA
    length = tibia
    print(f'A9+A8+C9  {A9+A8+C9}')
    print(f'A9+A8  {A9+A8}')
    angle = dega90[C9-A9+A8]
    # Angle in degrees
    plane = 'XZ'
    end_point = calculate_endpoint_and_plot(vlx, vly, vlz, length, angle, plane)
    ax.plot([vlx,end_point[0] ],[vly, end_point[1] ], [vlz, end_point[2]], color='black')
    tlx,tly,tlz=end_point[0],end_point[1],end_point[2]
    #------------------------------------------------------------------- FEmur
    length = femur
    print(f'A9  {A9}')
    angle = A9+A8+C9 # Angle in degrees
    print(f'temp  {A9+A8}')
    plane = 'XZ'
    end_point = calculate_endpoint_and_plot(tlx, tly, tlz, length, angle, plane)
    ax.plot([tlx,end_point[0] ],[tly, end_point[1] ], [tlz, end_point[2]], color='blue')
    #---------------------------    
    ax.set_xlim(-400, 400)
    ax.set_ylim(-400, 400)
    ax.set_zlim(0, 400)
    ax.set_xlabel('X')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y')
    ax.set_zlabel('Z')
    plt.draw()

# Set up the figure and axes
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
# Generate array of degrees
dega27 = np.arange(270, -90, -1)
dega90 = np.arange(90, -270, -1)
dega18 = np.arange(180, -180, -1)
# Create sliders
fy_slider = Slider(plt.axes([0.1, 0.04, 0.65, 0.03]), 'FY', -200, 200,valinit=50)
fx_slider = Slider(plt.axes([0.1, 0.12, 0.65, 0.03]), 'FX', -200, 200,valinit=-1)
rh_slider = Slider(plt.axes([0.1, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03]), 'RH', 0, 250, valinit=120)
# Attach update function to slidersfz_slider.on_changed(update)
fy_slider.on_changed(update)
fx_slider.on_changed(update)
rh_slider.on_changed(update)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Feedback: the downvotes were likely for the vague title. I have replaced it with something  bit more meaningful.

Comment: Thanks! i've been playing with this for days I'm sure I'm missing something but I don't know what ...Thanks again.

Comment: It may also be helpful to make a screenshot of what you get at present, so that readers can be drawn into answering your question.